# C# P/Invoked function from BPL returns same pointer to Delphi record regardless of input

Tags: c#, delphi

I am trying to use a function from foreign BPL package for which I don't have access to code.

While I have success in Delphi, in C# I am still getting same value, regardless of input.

**External usage of BPL in Delphi**

```
type
  PRecord = ^TRecord;
  TRecord = packed record
      S: string;
      LW: LongWord;
  end;    

function GetValue(W : Word) : PRecord; external 'package.bpl' name '@Unit@Function$qqrus';
```

Calling of `GetValue()` with different input returns different records, which is correct.

**External usage of BPL in C#**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct TRecord
{
    public string S;
    public int LW;
}
        
[DllImport("package.bpl", EntryPoint = "@Unit@Function$qqrus", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern IntPtr GetValue(ushort number);
    
public static TRecord GetDelphiValue(ushort number)
{
    var ptr = GetValue(number);
    return (TRecord) Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(TRecord))
}
```

Calling of `GetDelphiValue()` with different input always returns the same pointer and therefore the struct.

What I've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function GetValue(W : Word) : PRecord; 
  external 'package.bpl' name '@Unit@Function$qqrus';
```

This function uses Delphi's default calling convention, namely `register`. This is not supported by other tools, and so this function cannot be called from your C# code.

You will need to put a Delphi DLL in between your C# code and the Delphi package. That Delphi DLL will be able to call the `register` calling convention function, and can export a function with the `stdcall` calling convention for your C# code to call.

Additionally, you also have the opportunity to sort out any potential issues caused by the use of the Delphi `string` type, which again is private to Delphi.

For what it worth, I am highly sceptical that the function really does return a pointer to a record. I think it is more likely that this is a procedure that has the record as a `var` or `out` parameter. And I do think that there are very likely issues relating to the lifetime of that string. Realistically, you cannot expect to use a binary module for which you have no information about its interface.

Comment: Another reason this code won't work in non-Delphi tools is because it is a BPL instead of a DLL. A BPL is a special type of DLL that requires additional initializations after being loaded into memory via `LoadLibrary()`. Delphi has a `LoadPackage()` function for that very reason. Other tools don't.

Comment: What confuses me is that from C# I actually see a real record from an array handled by that function, although still the same.

I saw an older source code for that Delphi function and it is really returning a pointer to a record.

I thought that I can omit Delphi "middle" DLL, but obviously I can't.